# How can I batch-crop images to 6x4?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, batch

I have a bunch of images which are not 6x4 images.  How can I crop all the images to 6x4 and keep to the best quality possible at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) has a tool called [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html). That's your friend! ;)
Especially take a look at the [crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/command-line-options.html#crop) function.